# What is the correct way to get data from async function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback

Here I've implemented one function called fetchDetails, which I've used to get data using callback.
According to me the syntax of calling the function/ its callback is not correct. 
It everytime fires error that "callback is not a function".
How do I invoke callback to get that data from fetchDetails.

Already tried to return data instead callback(data);

```
            var flag = false;
                    function fetchDetail(serise, callback) {
                        if(responseData.body.data.length - 1 !== serise){
                            // process to fetch data from array of responsedata 
                        }
            else
                        {
            // Here if the serise is reached at length of the array then will true flag
                            flag = true;
                        }

                        if(flag){
                //if the flag is true then, wanted to get data which is callback by function fetchDetails()
                            callback(); // Here my callback get stuck and get error "Callback is not a function"
                return;
                        }
                        else
            {
                // Here increase serise for getting next element of an array
                            fetchMessage(++serise);
                        }
                   }
           fetchDetail(0,function(){
                      let data ={
                         isFound: 1,
                         detail: "detail found"
                      }
              callback(data);                
                   });
```

Expected result is to get data which is defined in `fetchDetail()` but the process stuck at

```
if (flag) { 
 callback();
}
```

Comment: Why not `flag = serise === (responseData.body.data.length - 1); if (!flag) {
    /* process to fetch data from array of responsedata  */ }`

Comment: You get the error in `callback(data)`. Because there `callback` means nothing.

Comment: @mplungjan I need solution regarding callback.

Comment: @deceze I'm new to nodejs and javascript. How do I get response from that.

Answer (score 0):

In your function fetchDetails, you are passing a function as the second parameter.
So inside fetchDetails, 'callback' is

```
function() {
   let data = {
      isFound: 1,
      detail: "detail found"
    }
    callback(data);
 }
```

which itself is calling something called callback (which is undefined).

I'm not entirely sure what your code is doing, but an example of passing through a callback could be something like this:

```
 let fetchDetails = function(callback) {
    fetch(url).then(function(data) {
        callback.call(this, data);
    });
 }

 fetchDetails(function(data) {
     console.log(data);
 });
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The error is not in the block

```
if (flag) { 
   callback();
}
```

The error is in the block

```
fetchDetail(0,function(){
      let data ={
      isFound: 1,
      detail: "detail found"
   }
   callback(data);                
});
```

because callback in this block is not define.

You can modify your code like this:

```
var flag = false;

function fetchDetail(serise, callback) {
  if (responseData.body.data.length - 1 !== serise) {
    // process to fetch data from array of responsedata 
  }
  else {
    // Here if the serise is reached at length of the array then will true flag
    flag = true;
  }
  if (flag == 0) {
    //if the flag is true then, wanted to get data which is callback by function fetchDetails()
    data = callback(); // Here my callback get stuck and get error "Callback is not a function"
    console.log(data)
    return;
  } else {
    // Here increase serise for getting next element of an array
    console.log('Not call callback')
  }
}
fetchDetail(0, function() {
  let data = {
    isFound: 1,
    detail: "detail found"
  }
  return data
  // console.log('Hello from callback')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Today it's easier to use async/await syntax for async functions:

```
// you can use await keyword only in async functions.
async function init(){  
    var value=await fetchDetails()  // See the await keyword
    console.log(value)              // hello
}

async function fetchDetail(serise) { // No callback parameter.

     var callback
     var promise=new Promise(resolve=>callback=resolve)

     // do your async work, call callback when you finish

     setTimeout(()=>{callback('hello')},1000)
     return promise
}
```